# Flash 5 "No Valid HTML Templates"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

So I just built a site using Flash 5  when I try to publish my site it tells me that there are "No Valid HTML Templates Available to Complete This Action." HOW TO SOLVE IT?

Answer (score 0):

In your publish settings uncheck the export to HTML option, then publish it and see what happens.

It sounds like your template file for making HTML is missing, try repairing or re-installing your installation of Flash Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Try run animate with administrative privileges